# can collaborative filtering recommendations provide a match percentage metric?

Tags: recommender-system, spark-mllib

I followed a couple tutorials about matrix factorisation with Spark (https://gerardnico.com/wiki/data_mining/collaborative_filtering one of them). I'm clear that I'm building a dataframe that fills in rating 'blanks' based on other observations

While getting those recommendations was straightforward, I would like to find out how 'relevant or accurate' an specific item recommendation is to you

I have the feeling these are 2 separate problems, but considering I have a matrix of user-items-ratings, is there some way to obtain that percentage? is there other algorithm I should run on top of the same model?

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not a complete answer, but just wanted to document the approach I took.

A further understanding of CF and matrix factorization made me realise the 'rating' column represents not just a user-provided value, but how relevant an item is already. Recommendations are given without paying attention to an item features, just its rating

I was able to calculate a new rating column (call it score), with a 0 to 100 value, that represented the sum of the user features I was after, hence resulting in what I was after

I also opted to complement the results with a content-based recommender (different algorithm). This one provides another 0 to 100 scoring based on the amount of tag/attributes matched between an item an a user